# VK API загрузка фото

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

При отправке multipart/form-data по полученному url, запрос

```
https://pu.vk.com/c639830/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=xxx&aid=-14&gid=0&hash=xxxx&rhash=xxxxx&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1
```

от сервера VK приходит полуправильный ответ(есть сервер, и hash, нету фото). Вот как приходит:

```
{"server":87899,"photo":"[]","hash":"xxxx"}
```

Вот как ожидается:

```
{
"server":123456,
"photos_list":"[{\"photo\":\"e9f2eba71b:y\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"123456852\",\"e65f\",\"Br4ir9YAvO8\",75,41],[\"m\",\"123456852\",\"e660\",\"Lqpe1N8s8zY\",130,71],[\"x\",\"123456852\",\"e661\",\"tRFbnaIP_4c\",604,330],[\"y\",\"123456852\",\"e662\",\"8JhBOy0qR6o\",748,409],[\"o\",\"123456852\",\"e663\",\"fn5KcewNluM\",130,87],[\"p\",\"123456852\",\"e664\",\"ESWOdpl7bvY\",200,133],\"kid\":\"569c3da3b168b347315aa5adc92a953a\",\"debug\":\"xsymyxyyyoypyqyry\"}]",
"aid":98754321,
"hash":"22b333dbbef7cd9b1f9829b5f8713f86"
}
```

Тестовый код

```
function get_web_page($url, $post = null)
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );


    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    if($post){
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

$for_upload = get_web_page("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?access_token=".$token."&group_id".$id);
$url_upload = json_decode($for_upload['content'])->response->upload_url;

$upload = get_web_page($url_upload, array("file1" => "test.jpg"));
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какой конкретно запрос Вы отправляете? Добавьте его к вашему вопросу.

Comment: запрос вида: https://pu.vk.com/c639830/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=xxx&aid=-14&gid=0&hash=xxxx&rhash=xxxxx&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1

Answer (score 2):

Вот этот код не передаёт саму фотографию, а передаёт просто массив `['file1' => 'test.jpg']`:

```
get_web_page($url_upload, array("file1" => "test.jpg"));
```

Судя по [этой документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%2B%D0%BD%D0%B0%2B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83) вы должны делать приблизительно так:

```
get_web_page($url_upload, ['photo' => ['file1' => file_get_contents($pathToFile)]]);
```

Comment: действительно ошибка, спасибо. но, север по прежнему возвращает пустой массив фото.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_path = "@$photo"; //где $photo - ПОЛНЫЙ путь до файла
get_web_page($url_upload, ['photo' => ['file1' => $image_path]]);
```

Попробуйте так

1.Curl, если я не ошибаюсь, не понимает относительных путей.

2.Чтобы передать файл, необходимо перед путём файла поставить "@"

Answer (score 0):

В PHP 5.6+ появилась новая возможность передачи файлов используя `CURLFile($localFile)` вместо `'@'.$localFile`:

```
<?
$request_params = array( 
    'image_type' => '510x128',
    'access_token' => 'xxx',
    'v' => '5.92' 
); 

$t = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.getAppImageUploadServer?'. http_build_query($request_params)));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $t->response->upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("image" => new CURLFile(dirname(__FILE__).'\img.jpg')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$request_params = array( 
    'hash' => $result->hash,
    'image' => $result->image,
    'access_token' => 'xxx',
    'v' => '5.92' 
); 

print_r(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.saveAppImage?'. http_build_query($request_params)));

?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ответ пояснением, что делает этот фрагмент кода.

Comment: In PHP 5.6+, the new way to transfer files is to use new CURLFile($localFile), instead of '@'.$localFile.